# Java split a string by using a regex

Tags: java, regex, parsing, split, tokenize

I am trying to take out a specified string between double quotes from a string. Like,

```
"foo ,bar", test, example, 2.33
```

I have tried already

```
String str = "\"foo ,bar", test, example, 2.33";
// take the string which starts and ends with quotes
str.split("^(").*(")$");
```

but doesnt seem to work. This surrounded string could be any where not only at the beginning.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: I just want to get "foo ,bar" string out.